# How can I know which radio button is selected in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, radio-button

i have 3 radio buttons and once i click any one of them it should update 2 text views. One text view for the name and other text view for the price.
When i click on the radio button the name gets updated but i am facing issue with how to get the item price from the array. Each of the radio button has different pricing.

Code:

```
     pizzaSizeRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        pizzaSizeRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
//                Radio button checked
                sizeSelect = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
                selectedSize.setText(sizeSelect.getTag().toString());

//                how to display the price from array
                sizePrice = array_price_list[].getItem_price();
                totalPriceDisplay.setText(sizePrice);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: I don't have enough information. Do you just need to know how to get the correct index for the array? Because I'm not sure what you're doing here: sizePrice = array_price_list[].getItem_price();

Comment: @MikeM. sure. Thanks

Comment: @GavinWright i will update it

Comment: @GavinWright i have an items class which has 2 variables: item name and item price. i added values to it like this                                                    
 private Items size_small = new Items ("Small",5);  i add all the values into an array and now want to select only the 3 values for radio button

Comment: Does this mean you have a 3-element array, and each element corresponds to one of the 3 RadioButtons?

Comment: @GavinWright yes each element in array corresponds to each radio button. So when radio button is clicked it displays the price and name for that specific radio button

Comment: Then just do like Zahoor Saleem suggests below. The index of the array is just an integer 0, 1, or 2. So you just set an int variable equal to 0,1, or, 2 depending on which RadioButton is pressed.

Comment: i tried doing the way Zahoor Saleem suggested but the price in textview is still not updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can implement switch Radiogroup checkedId

pizzaSizeRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

```
    pizzaSizeRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch(checkedId){
                case R.id.radio0://Radio button id
                    // do operations specific to this selection
                    break;
                case R.id.radio1://Radio button id
                    // do operations specific to this selection
                    break;
                case R.id.radio2://Radio button id
                    // do operations specific to this selection
                    break;
            }   
        }
    });
```

or check the selected radio button

```
     int selectedId = pizzaSizeRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Comment: how to proceed with this: int selectedId = pizzaSizeRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

Comment: if(selectedid == R1){ array_price_list[0].getItem_price();}else if(selectedid == R2){array_price_list[1].getItem_price();}else if(selectedid == R3){array_price_list[2].getItem_price();} etc

Comment: i tried doing this way but the textview for price still doesnt get updated

Comment: share your main class and xml file

Comment: doing it using switch case statements. it works fine

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally clear what is the values in the price array you have or what is the implementation of your getItem_price() method.

But it seems that you have set the name in the tag of the radio buttons and that is why you are able to get it and populate your selectedSize textview.

As much as i understand your problem, you could follow two approaches

Approach 1 :
create a list of a pizza object with name and price and an id.
Set the id in the tag of the radio button. that way you can get the name and price both using the id you will get form radioButton.getTag().

Approach 2:
Concatenate the name and price with a |, e.g, size1|25 and set that to the tag of radio button.
Then you can use split on getTag to get the name and price both.

Hope this helps you with your problem.

Comment: i have an items class which has 2 variables: item name and item price. i added values to it like this private Items size_small = new Items ("Small",5); i add all the values into an array and now want to select only the 3 values for radio button

Comment: You could another variable to your class named id. Then you can set that id in the tag of radio button. Getting the tag from selected radio button you can use that id to get the corresponding name and price. But you need to create the radio group dynamically and set the tag uaing your list.

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose you can use switch please follow this

```
radiobuttoncheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rgroup, int r_id) {
        switch(r_id){
            case R.id.rbid1:
                //show toast here to get idea
                break;
            case R.id.rbid2:

               //show toast here to get idea

                break;
        }   
    }
});
```

Comment: is there any other way to do this other than switch statement ?

Comment: yea, use multiple if-s